# Image processing libraries in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing

From where can I get image processing libraries in C# .Net?

Comment: CodePlex, GitHub, GoogleCode are the best places to find such libraries. First, I would advice to start from here: http://is.gd/U5h4SD ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**edit:** Check out the list here https://github.com/quozd/awesome-dotnet/blob/master/README.md#image-processing:

- [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net/) - Add commands to image URLs to get altered versions in milliseconds. Resizing, editing etc of images in real-time.
- [ImageProcessor](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor) - Open-source .NET library to manipulate images on-the-fly.
- [DynamicImage](http://dynamicimage.apphb.com/) - High-performance open-source image manipulation library for ASP.NET.
- [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) - Extracts Exif, IPTC, XMP, ICC and other metadata from image files.
- [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) - Cross-platform .NET wrapper for the OpenCV library.
- [DotImaging](https://github.com/dajuric/dot-imaging) - Minimalistic .NET imaging portable platform
- [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET) - .NET wrapper for the ImageMagick library.
- [OpenCvSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/) - Cross platform wrapper of OpenCV for .NET Framework.

---

Check the [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) library. It is a set of libraries in which you'll find an image processing and a vision library.

Answer (score 6):

There [emguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) (for .NET) that is based on C++ OpenCV, which is very popular.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Craig's Utility Library  http://cul.codeplex.com/

> Image manipulation available:
>
> - Cropping, resizing, rotating,    flipping
> - To black and white or sepia tone
> - Threshold and edge detection    (including Sobel and Laplace)
> - Text drawing, watermarks, object    drawing helpers
> - Taking a screenshot which spans    monitors
> - RGB Histograms
> - Various convolution filters such as    sharpen, sobel emboss, etc. along
>     with the ability to create your own
>     easily
> - Various other filters such as    "jitter", pixelate, sin wave, median
>     filter, and dilation, -red/green/blue 
>     filters
> - Multiple blurring techniques    including box blur, Gaussian blur,
>     Kuwahara, and Symmetric Nearest
>     Neighbor blur
> - Bump map and Normal map helpers
> - ASCII art generator
> - Adjust brightness, gamma, and    contrast

Also you may like: [OpenCVSharp](http://code.google.com/p/opencvsharp) and [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com) - by the way, EmguCV the most advanced one.

Answer (score 1):

I know a third-party toolkit named leadtools that provides many image processing functions. Also, it supports hundreds of image formats. You can find more information here:
http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing/default.htm

Comment: LeadTools is a very advanced imade processing library. I used it few years ago for medical image analysis

Answer (score 0):

Beside the framework functions I like [Image_Processing_Lab](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx).