# C# Remove gradient background from image

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, gradient

I have an image loaded into a Bitmap in C# with a gradient background from a document i scanned in.
An example of it could be like the picture below:

My goal in C# is now to remove the background so that I have a solid white background. Now I myself can't seem to find a way to do this. Is there a way to achieve this in a way?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to look at specialized image processing libraries - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881031/image-processing-libraries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using `LockBits`.

The premise is if it's not black then change it to white.

1. It will be magnitudes faster the `GetPixel` and `SetPixel`
2. It works with the raw data in *memory* using *pointers*
3. *iterates* through every *pixel*
4. Checks the *color* and changes it to white if needed
5. Saves the image

<sub>***Note** : obviously this will destroy any antialiasing and smoothing, it will fail for certain image types, and other assorted issues.*</sub>

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(@"D:\Test.png"))
{
   var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
   var white = Color.White.ToArgb();
   var black = Color.Black.ToArgb();

   try
   {
      var length = (int*)data.Scan0 + bmp.Height * bmp.Width;
      for (var p = (int*)data.Scan0; p < length; p++)
         if (*p != black) *p = white;
   }
   finally
   {
      // unlock the bitmap
      bmp.UnlockBits(data);
      bmp.Save(@"D:\Output.Bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
   }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I see how this would work so i'm definitly gonna try this. But now i am also wondering is this code convertable to for example if there is a photo inside of the scanned document that has mulitple colors inside it of which you don't know which colors they are?

Comment: @DLP as long as the colors arnt black its fine, however i think you can see how it works, so you should be able to modify it simply for other needs

Answer (score 0):

If you know the gradient colors (e.g. only part of RGB color responsible for red changes) or at least the color of text (e.g. if it is always black) then you can iterate through all of image's pixels and then:

1. Use `GetPixel()` to get pixel color.
2. Check if it is text (black).
3. If it is, then move to the next pixel.
4. If it isn't, then change color to white with `SetPixel()`.

For gradient it should be enough. For more complex backgrounds it would need a more complex algorithm.